# Stop compiler to suggest candidates for overloaded template, expand PRETTY_FUNCTION in static_assert

Tags: c++, templates

My code use templates heavily. I have a number of overloaded functions

```
auto operator>>(byte_vector_view&bvv, Type&&) ->byte_vector_view&;
```

This works fine until unknown by this function family type is passed to function:

```
bvv >> my_custom;
```

User should simply see one error message:

> There no implementation for operator>>(byte_vector_view&bvv, my_custom_type&)

instead we see a very long manuscript:

<sub>*how to put this under spoiler?*</sub>

```
itm.cpp:184:18: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('byte_vector_view' and 'named_value<std::__1::vector<unsigned char, std::__1::allocator<unsigned char> > >')
            ((bvv>>elements),...);
              ~~~^ ~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits:4345:23: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'operator>>(byte_vector_view &, std::__1::tuple<named_value<std::__1::vector<unsigned char, std::__1::allocator<unsigned char> > > > &)::(anonymous class)::operator()<named_value<std::__1::vector<unsigned char, std::__1::allocator<unsigned char> > > >' requested here
_LIBCPP_INVOKE_RETURN(_VSTD::forward<_Fp>(__f)(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...))
                      ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/__config:508:15: note: expanded from macro '_VSTD'
#define _VSTD std::_LIBCPP_NAMESPACE
              ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/tuple:1375:5: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template '__invoke_constexpr' [with _Fp = (lambda at itm.cpp:183:9), _Args = <named_value<std::__1::vector<unsigned char, std::__1::allocator<unsigned char> > > &>]
    _VSTD::__invoke_constexpr(
    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/__config:508:15: note: expanded from macro '_VSTD'
#define _VSTD std::_LIBCPP_NAMESPACE
              ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/tuple:1372:26: note: in instantiation of exception specification for '__apply_tuple_impl<(lambda at itm.cpp:183:9), std::__1::tuple<named_value<std::__1::vector<unsigned char, std::__1::allocator<unsigned char> > > > &, 0>' requested here
constexpr decltype(auto) __apply_tuple_impl(_Fn && __f, _Tuple && __t,
                         ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/tuple:1384:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::__apply_tuple_impl<(lambda at itm.cpp:183:9), std::__1::tuple<named_value<std::__1::vector<unsigned char, std::__1::allocator<unsigned char> > > > &, 0>' requested here
    _VSTD::__apply_tuple_impl(
           ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/tuple:1382:26: note: in instantiation of exception specification for 'apply<(lambda at itm.cpp:183:9), std::__1::tuple<named_value<std::__1::vector<unsigned char, std::__1::allocator<unsigned char> > > > &>' requested here
constexpr decltype(auto) apply(_Fn && __f, _Tuple && __t)
                         ^
itm.cpp:182:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::apply<(lambda at itm.cpp:183:9), std::__1::tuple<named_value<std::__1::vector<unsigned char, std::__1::allocator<unsigned char> > > > &>' requested here
    apply(
    ^
itm.cpp:461:20: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'operator>><std::__1::tuple<named_value<std::__1::vector<unsigned char, std::__1::allocator<unsigned char> > > > >' requested here
                bvv>>tvs;
                   ^
itm.cpp:427:12: note: in instantiation of member function 'make_converter(bool, std::__1::tuple<named_value<ringnet::proto::opcode>, named_value<command_address> > &&, named_value<std::__1::vector<unsigned char, std::__1::allocator<unsigned char> > > &&)::Ret::from_byte_vector_view' requested here
    struct Ret:converter_virtual{
           ^
itm.cpp:537:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'make_converter<std::__1::tuple<named_value<ringnet::proto::opcode>, named_value<command_address> >, named_value<std::__1::vector<unsigned char, std::__1::allocator<unsigned char> > > >' requested here
    return make_converter(false,forward<Prefix>(prefix),forward<Ts>(values)...);
           ^
itm.cpp:931:18: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'make_converter<std::__1::tuple<named_value<ringnet::proto::opcode>, named_value<command_address> >, named_value<std::__1::vector<unsigned char, std::__1::allocator<unsigned char> > > >' requested here
     /*response*/make_converter(
                 ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits:4840:3: note: candidate function template not viable: no known conversion from 'byte_vector_view' to 'std::byte' for 1st argument
  operator>> (byte  __lhs, _Integer __shift) noexcept
  ^
itm.cpp:147:19: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'named_value<std::__1::vector<unsigned char, std::__1::allocator<unsigned char> > >' to 'uint8_t &' (aka 'unsigned char &') for 2nd argument
byte_vector_view& operator>>(byte_vector_view&bvv, uint8_t&ui8){
                  ^
itm.cpp:151:19: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'named_value<std::__1::vector<unsigned char, std::__1::allocator<unsigned char> > >' to 'std::__1::string &' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > &') for 2nd argument
byte_vector_view& operator>>(byte_vector_view&bvv, string&str){
                  ^
itm.cpp:156:19: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'named_value<std::__1::vector<unsigned char, std::__1::allocator<unsigned char> > >' to 'named_value<std::__1::string> &' (aka 'named_value<basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > > &') for 2nd argument
byte_vector_view& operator>>(byte_vector_view&bvv, named_value<string>&av){
                  ^
itm.cpp:161:6: note: candidate template ignored: requirement 'is_integral_v<std::__1::vector<unsigned char, std::__1::allocator<unsigned char> > > || is_same_v<std::__1::vector<unsigned char, std::__1::allocator<unsigned char> >, ringnet::proto::opcode> || is_same_v<std::__1::vector<unsigned char, std::__1::allocator<unsigned char> >, command_address>' was not satisfied [with T = std::__1::vector<unsigned char, std::__1::allocator<unsigned char> >]
auto operator>>(byte_vector_view&bvv, named_value<T>&av) ->enable_if_t<is_integral_v<T> || is_same_v<T,opcode> || is_same_v<T,command_address>, byte_vector_view&>{
     ^
itm.cpp:181:6: note: candidate template ignored: requirement 'is_tuple<named_value<std::__1::vector<unsigned char, std::__1::allocator<unsigned char> > > >' was not satisfied [with TupleT = named_value<std::__1::vector<unsigned char, std::__1::allocator<unsigned char> > >]
auto operator>>(byte_vector_view&bvv, TupleT&tu) ->enable_if_t<is_tuple<TupleT>,byte_vector_view&> {
     ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:521:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_istream<type-parameter-0-0, type-parameter-0-1>' against 'byte_vector_view'
operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __is, _CharT* __s)
^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:570:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_istream<char, type-parameter-0-0>' against 'byte_vector_view'
operator>>(basic_istream<char, _Traits>& __is, unsigned char* __s)
^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:578:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_istream<char, type-parameter-0-0>' against 'byte_vector_view'
operator>>(basic_istream<char, _Traits>& __is, signed char* __s)
^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:585:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_istream<type-parameter-0-0, type-parameter-0-1>' against 'byte_vector_view'
operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __is, _CharT& __c)
^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:613:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_istream<char, type-parameter-0-0>' against 'byte_vector_view'
operator>>(basic_istream<char, _Traits>& __is, unsigned char& __c)
^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:621:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_istream<char, type-parameter-0-0>' against 'byte_vector_view'
operator>>(basic_istream<char, _Traits>& __is, signed char& __c)
^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:1219:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_istream<type-parameter-0-0, type-parameter-0-1>' against 'byte_vector_view'
operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __is, _Tp&& __x)
^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:1287:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_istream<type-parameter-0-0, type-parameter-0-1>' against 'byte_vector_view'
operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __is,
^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:1419:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_istream<type-parameter-0-0, type-parameter-0-1>' against 'byte_vector_view'
operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __is, bitset<_Size>& __x)
^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/iomanip:302:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_istream<type-parameter-0-0, type-parameter-0-1>' against 'byte_vector_view'
operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __is, const __iom_t7<_MoneyT>& __x)
```

*It's hard to read and understand where is the problem exactly and therefore hard to fix the problem*

**Need more clear explanation**

I found one straightforward way to suppress excess output:

```
template<typename UnknownType>
auto operator>>(byte_vector_view&bvv, UnknownType&&) ->byte_vector_view& {
    static_assert(false);
    return bvv;
}
```

With it compiler gives a quiet short error message, too short:

```
itm.cpp:192:5: error: static_assert failed
    static_assert(false);
    ^             ~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I'd like to see in which function the error appeared and a trace how compiler come there:

```
template<typename UnknownType>
auto operator>>(byte_vector_view&bvv, UnknownType&&) ->byte_vector_view& {
    static_assert(false&&__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    return bvv;
}
```

```
itm.cpp:192:5: error: static_assert failed
    static_assert(false && __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
itm.cpp:184:18: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'operator>><named_value<std::__1::vector<unsigned char, std::__1::allocator<unsigned char> > > &>' requested here
            ((bvv>>elements),...);
                 ^
itm.cpp:461:20: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'operator>><std::__1::tuple<named_value<std::__1::vector<unsigned char, std::__1::allocator<unsigned char> > > > >' requested here
                bvv>>tvs;
                   ^
itm.cpp:427:12: note: in instantiation of member function 'make_converter(bool, std::__1::tuple<named_value<ringnet::proto::opcode>, named_value<command_address> > &&, named_value<std::__1::vector<unsigned char, std::__1::allocator<unsigned char> > > &&)::Ret::from_byte_vector_view' requested here
    struct Ret:converter_virtual{
           ^
itm.cpp:537:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'make_converter<std::__1::tuple<named_value<ringnet::proto::opcode>, named_value<command_address> >, named_value<std::__1::vector<unsigned char, std::__1::allocator<unsigned char> > > >' requested here
    return make_converter(false,forward<Prefix>(prefix),forward<Ts>(values)...);
           ^
itm.cpp:931:18: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'make_converter<std::__1::tuple<named_value<ringnet::proto::opcode>, named_value<command_address> >, named_value<std::__1::vector<unsigned char, std::__1::allocator<unsigned char> > > >' requested here
     /*response*/make_converter(
                 ^
1 error generated.
```

And this is almost looks like I want but Clang++ does not expand `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` in `static_assert`.

#### Is there a way to put expanded `UnknownType` to `static_assert`'s message?

I also tried

```
static_assert(false,__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
```

but it gives

```
error: expected string literal for diagnostic message in static_assert
```

Comment: Have you tried `=delete;`ing the template?

Comment: not before. but tried as you suggested. This gives `error: attempt to use a deleted function` and continues suggest candidates - produces very-very long output.

Comment: [Like here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uM3VXwEZ0GcJ8Plv) ?

Comment: yes. please write your answer with code and this link. I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename UnknownType>
struct Type_Not_Supported : std::false_type {};

template <typename UnknownType>
auto operator>>(byte_vector_view& bvv, UnknownType&&) -> byte_vector_view& {
    static_assert(Type_Not_Supported<UnknownType>{});
    return bvv;
}
```

In Clang, this yields:

```
prog.cc:10:5: error: static_assert failed due to requirement 'Type_Not_Supported<int>{}'
    static_assert(Type_Not_Supported<UnknownType>{});
    ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.cc:17:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'operator>><int>' requested here
    bvv >> 1;
        ^
1 error generated.
```

In GCC:

```
prog.cc: In instantiation of 'byte_vector_view& operator>>(byte_vector_view&, UnknownType&&) [with UnknownType = int]':
prog.cc:17:12:   required from here
prog.cc:10:19: error: static assertion failed
   10 |     static_assert(Type_Not_Supported<UnknownType>{});
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/F1O4bTfg3CAhTxQg)